Problems with Data Network Analysis tutorial
I am using the tutorial to learn how to analyze RNAseq data. Please note that I select exactly the commands indicated in the tutorial. And in the fifth step (Data Integration) no rows are added because the message appears about a conflict between the "Key Column for Network" of the imported .csv file and the String network already opened.

Please provide a link to the resource you are using, along with the relevant code which caused the error. Else it is impossible for anyone to help out - no one can be sure which resource/tools/commands you ran!
